# why locate all on screen in pyautogui returns multiple similar results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I have pretty much read through all the existing doc and cannot find an answer.

So here is the simple code:

`for pos in pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen('image.png', confidence=0.9, grayscale=False):`
      `print(pos)`

I was expecting it to find 3 different locations of this image.
However, the results are:

```
Box(left=1199, top=543, width=52, height=56)
Box(left=1200, top=543, width=52, height=56)
Box(left=1201, top=543, width=52, height=56)
Box(left=1198, top=544, width=52, height=56)
Box(left=1199, top=544, width=52, height=56)
Box(left=1200, top=544, width=52, height=56)
Box(left=1201, top=544, width=52, height=56)
Box(left=1202, top=544, width=52, height=56)
Box(left=1199, top=545, width=52, height=56)
Box(left=1200, top=545, width=52, height=56)
Box(left=1201, top=545, width=52, height=56)
Box(left=821, top=853, width=52, height=56)
Box(left=820, top=854, width=52, height=56)
Box(left=821, top=854, width=52, height=56)
Box(left=822, top=854, width=52, height=56)
Box(left=821, top=855, width=52, height=56)
Box(left=1202, top=1483, width=52, height=56)
Box(left=1203, top=1483, width=52, height=56)
Box(left=1204, top=1483, width=52, height=56)
Box(left=1202, top=1484, width=52, height=56)
Box(left=1203, top=1484, width=52, height=56)
Box(left=1204, top=1484, width=52, height=56)
```

How can I tell it to show me results that is at least "x" pixels away ?

BTW, changing the confidence score does not help. it is either multiple or none.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have pyautogui installed at the moment, but have in years past, so I get what it's doing.  Think you need to compare positions with already found locations, then only add them if it finds one that's greater than your chosen threshhold.  I don't know if they have a built-in function for that, you'd have to look.  Either way, it'd essentially do something like this:

```
positions = []
threshhold = 8

for p in pyautogui .locateAllOnScreen( 'image.png', confidence=0.9, grayscale=False ):
    for pos in positions:
        if abs( pos['left'] -p['left'] ) > threshhold \
        and abs( pos['top'] -p['top'] ) > threshhold:
            positions .append( pos )

for pos in positions:
    print( pos )
```

Comment: Yes, indeed, Thank you so much. I end up comparing a threshold for its findings as well. They should have that built-in. What I did is, left+top > threshold and I just record the last one and compare the current one.